# How to make info window popup like popup window

Tags: android, infowindow

how i can doing the info window pop up like the popup window?
the info window is display like the photo

[image]

and how i can display it on the center of the screen like popup window???
and button inside all can function???

this is the code i call the info window

```
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(final Marker arg0) {

            View v = 
            getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.markerlayout, 
            null);
            int zoom = (int)mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new 
            LatLng(arg0.getPosition().latitude + (double)90/Math.pow(2, 
            zoom), arg0.getPosition().longitude), zoom);
            Button dismiss = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.dismissbtn);
            dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    arg0.hideInfoWindow();
                }

            });
            return v;

        }
        });
```

and this is the XML of my custom info window

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/location_popup_bg">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dismissbtn"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:background="@drawable/close" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/popup_img"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dismissbtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/location1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/popup_img"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:text="NADEJE MAHKOTA PARADE"
    android:textColor="#2e3192"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/popup_divider"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/popup_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="G-23B, EG 4 &amp; EG 5, Ground floor, Mahkota Parade,
    75000 Melaka Mahkota."
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/address"
    android:text="11.00am – 10.00pm (Mon – Sun)"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time"
    android:text="Tel No : 06-2843469"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:text="CALL US"
    android:textColor="#2e3192"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tel"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:text="DIRECTIONS"
    android:textColor="#2e3192"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/dismissbtn"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

Comment: how to add popup window function for a marker?